# **Ionic-Angular** HTML 5 Video Tag Controls Not Working in Full Screen

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework, ionic3

Am trying to load video in my ionic app using html 5 video tag . It works fine in normal screen but when i switch to full screen mode, the video controls are displayed but unable to click . This happens on Android so far (works fine on browser), I haven't tested the app on iOS.

This is the simple html code for the video display. Any help would be so appreciated, thank you.

```
<div class="video-container">
<video src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" controls width="100%" poster="https://previews.123rf.com/images/andreus/andreus1409/andreus140900437/31970710-colored-trash-bins-used-to-recycle-paper-plastic-and-glass-digital-illustration--Stock-Photo.jpg">Thiết Bị Của Bạn Không Hỗ Trợ HTML5 videos.</video>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your android version and you can try https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: @ Manoj Bhardwaj      Thank for your sugesstion, but I eneded up with a failure when building Android apk with this error: Execution failed for task ':app:processArm64DebugResources'.

Answer (score 2):

For playing video in ionic you can always use streaming media plugin given by ionic.

```
import { StreamingMedia } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';
```

then create object of the class in constructor like

```
constructor(public streamingMedia: StreamingMedia) {}
```

finally you can call the play event of video simply like,

```
let options = {
        shouldAutoClose:true,
            successCallback: () => { console.log('Video played') },
            errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error while playing video.'); },
        };

        this.streamingMedia.playVideo("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4", options);
```

Comment: Thank you :D i would try it as soon as I can. Just one question, would this plugin be able to play videos in normal inline-mode (in a div or card,etc) instead of going full screen right in the 1st place?

Comment: No, it will run in fullscreen mode only.

Comment: I am facing an issue in iOS. I am not getting either success/failure callback. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link for bug Execution failed for task ':app:processArm64DebugResources'. https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues/205 and if you don't want control option on your video player then you can try streaming media plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/  but if you need controls and try to playing video over card or div then you can use crosswalk and other case is that when you used crosswalk then your will app take more size that is around 15 mb if you have no issue with app size then you can go with crosswalk

There is another library by npm that is videogular| The HTML5 video player for AngularJS http://www.videogular.com/  by using this there is no problem with app size and you also able to use many features

I also create my playlist and videoplayer by using videogular

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SqLc87Y02KKA44nwcgX3fZs9cf-gf2telajjnzhzlOeLA0V6MYiNMd9Yvgg91wuG3Q=w1366-h637-rw

Comment: Thank Mr, I've implemented the videogular 2 in my project but the video it self doesn't fit into the ion-card and when I tried to go full-screen, it just shrink itself to a tiny box. I would like to know how to achieve the exact design like what you have in your screenshot. Below is my screenshot:

http://oi65.tinypic.com/zu2j3c.jpg